# Is it possible to include directory information in spark.read.csv?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Scenario:

I wrote CSV data with something like

```
df.write.partitionBy("foo", "bar").csv("hdfs:///quux/bletch")
```

The CSV files in the `hdfs://quux/bletch/foo=baz/bar=moo` directories all lack the `foo` and `bar` columns.

How can I read that back in to get these columns back? Please don't tell me I have to read every directory individually, add the data manually and do a big, fat `union`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark will create those columns for you if you read CSV file the same way back (except that you don't have to specify `partitionBy`) It is also not a problem to call `load()` on a directory.

This example will do exactly what you want:

```
spark.read.format("csv").load("hdfs://quux/bleetch")
```

where `spark` is `SparkSession`.

Comment: I haven't anticipated it was THAT simple... Spark surprises me every day, they really think about a lot one might need.

Answer (score 0):

Try partition discovery.

By passing path/to/table to either SparkSession.read.parquet or SparkSession.read.load, Spark SQL will automatically extract the partitioning information from the paths. Now the schema of the returned DataFrame becomes:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
```